# Function fails on the second time i call it

Tags: javascript, ajax

this is my code:

```
 <script language="javascript">
    function refresh() {
        try {
            xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {}
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = triggered;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.php");
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }

    function triggered() {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
            document.getElementById("ins").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:refresh();">Refresh List</a>
```

The functions fails on the second time i call it,

```
Error: document.getElementById("loading") is null
```

Very strange, any fix for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the loading div from outside of the ins div:

```
<div id="loading"></div>  
<div id="ins"></div>
```

and change the javascript to the following:

```
function triggered() {  
    if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {  
        document.getElementById("ins").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;  
    }  
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display =  
                (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) ? "none" : "block";
}
```

This will hide the loading div for you when you finish and will re-show it next time you invoke this method.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible that `loading` is a child of `ins` and is overwritten by `triggered()`?

Comment: yes, but that the only way it worked for me.
<div id="ins"><div id="loading"></div</div>

Comment: You are overwriting `ins`, thus destroying `loading`. You need to place `loading` elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on JavaScript, but I guess:

The call to `document.getElementById("loading")` is not limited to `xmlhttp.readyState==4`.

It is called for all `readyStates` from 0 to 4. If the line

```
document.getElementById("ins").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

makes significant changes to the page (probably `"remove"` the element `"loading"`), the following

```
document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
```

leads to an error.